# Powershell: script to find allowedServerVariables in applicationHost.config check for duplicate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, powershell

I am trying add a new server variable

```
Add-WebConfiguration /system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables -atIndex 0 -value @{name="HTTP_COOKIE"}
```

but I am getting following error

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty : Filename: 
Error: Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'Test'
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filt ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-WebConfigurationProperty], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.AddConfigurationPropertyCommand
```

I could suppress using try catch block but would like to check if the variable already exists and skip Adding if it already exists.

Can anyone let me know how I can do this check?

Comment: [Get-WebConfigurationProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/get-webconfigurationproperty?view=winserver2012-ps)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@marsze way has done using Get-WebConfiguration.

my answer is using Get-WebConfigurationProperty. Both will work.

```
Write-Host "Getting allowed server variables..."
$allowedServerVariables = Get-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables/add" -Name name
Write-Host "Found $($allowedServerVariables.Length)..."

if ( ($allowedServerVariables -eq $null) -or ( $allowedServerVariables | ?{ $_.Value -eq "HTTP_COOKIE1" } ).Length -eq 0 ) {
    #Configure IIS To Allow 'HTTPS' as a server variable - Must be done at a applicationhosts.config level
    Write-Host "Adding HTTPS to allowed server variables..."
    Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables" -name "." -value @{name='HTTP_COOKIE1'}
}

Write-Host "Getting allowed server variables...Finished"
```

Answer (score 6):

Try adding the following check for example:

```
$path = "/system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables"
$value = "HTTP_COOKIE"
if ((Get-WebConfiguration $path).Collection.Name -notcontains $value) {
    Add-WebConfiguration $path -AtIndex 0 -Value @{ name = $value }
}
```

Comment: Will this work if I have more than one server variable?

Comment: @RajGan Yes (if you don't have a super-old PS version). But you can simply try it out.

Comment: Can we do similar with Get-WebConfigurationProperty?

Comment: Found this https://gist.github.com/ducas/b16dfd1d9ba91da7fd53 to check thru Get-WebConfigurationProperty